# problem with the curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

i am trying to build a road with guard railing.modeled a road and railings seperately like this--
[image: road]

then applied array mod on both of the objects and it looks like this--
[image: road array]

then i tried to bend the road a little upwards and downwards with a curve modifier pointing to a nurbspath. it was a disaster. the road looks ok but the railing are bent,skewed,stretched( i don't know what is the exact word for this) -[image: after curve]

i need help to know if I can apply the curve modifier to those rails without damaging their actual shape. thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6708" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6708/)

Comment: I can't open it because the curves make my 2.8 crash, anyway, maybe make sure that you put your road section at the beginning of your curve, also apply the RotScale of both the curve and the road, and maybe in the N panel check the Radius and Tilt of your curve's vertices?